# Python 3 Trying to login minecraft with Requests Module

Tags: python, cookies

I am trying to make this Minecraft login in Python but I can't seem to get it to work. The code I tried didn't work but I added the cookie.

Or any way I can get the cookie? I am pretty sure there is a way but I am new to Python `requests` and never tried getting a cookie with Python.

Any help would be great thanks!

Error:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe "C:/Users/Shrekt/PycharmProjects/Python 3/untitleds/gg.py"

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/Shrekt/PycharmProjects/Python 3/untitleds/gg.py", line 22, in <module>
cookie = page.cookies['authenticityToken']
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 276, in __getitem__
return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 331, in   _find_no_duplicates
raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='authenticityToken', domain=None, path=None"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Code:

```
import requests

user = "Username"
passw = "password"

header = {"Host": "minecraft.net",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0",
      "Referer": "https://minecraft.net/login",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}

with requests.session() as page:

cookie = page.cookies['authenticityToken']

login_data = dict(authenticityToken=cookie, redirect='https://minecraft.net/', username=user, password=passw, remember='true')

page.post('https://minecraft.net/login', data=login_data, headers=header)

page2 = page.get('https://minecraft.net/')

print(page2)

print("Done Logged in!")
```

Comment: That error is because you don't have a cookie set for `authenticityToken` in your current session. Thus it throws a `KeyError` exception. It's like trying to extract a value from a dictionary without an existing key. Would you mind printing all of the values inside of `page.cookies`? This would confirm my belief.

Comment: Well thats all the code i have using it

Comment: @Shrekt what thimble was asking for was to see what page.cookies actually is. Aka. can you please add `print page.cookies` to the end of your script and show up what it prints.

Comment: oh alright sorry x.x

Comment: <<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[]>
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[<Cookie PLAY_ERRORS= for minecraft.net/>, <Cookie PLAY_FLASH= for minecraft.net/>, <Cookie PLAY_SESSION="f2715538f344604bd4bbe027961f4d30c609dc53-___ID=a4a2af49-22dc-4f92-8b68-f77425c4539f&___AT=31ad407da76a7a3c3f9ad876c8e1c99a5f3c9bad" for minecraft.net/>]>  There you go ty for the help by the way